# Redirect a port from VM to local interface

Tags: virtualization, iptables, port-forwarding

I am not very well versed in iptables, so I apologize for a bit lame question.
What I need to do is to redirect port from a VM running on a private network the outside world.

VM, that is running on a server has, say, ip address 10.1.1.100. I need to forward port 8080 from that VM onto servers port 8080 on interface,say eth1 that is connected to the other private network. 
How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Port forwarding in common case:*

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination=10.1.1.100:8080
```

But in same cases you should add some SNAT's or change routing.

**Note:** do not forget check **FORWARD** chain